# Why don't decorators work on integer range partitioned bigquery tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I created an integer range partitioned bigquery table similar to one described in the tutorial:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE
   mydataset.newtable
 PARTITION BY
   RANGE_BUCKET(customer_id, GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100, 1))
 AS SELECT 1 AS customer_id, DATE "2019-10-01" AS date1
```

However, trying to extract a single partition into a bucket, running in bash

```sh
bq extract myproject:mydataset.newtable\$1 gs://mybucket/newtable.csv
```

I get an error "partition key is not valid". Why? How do I find the valid keys?

Similarly I cannot use the decorator to select from a specific partition using query composer:
`select from mydataset.newtable$0` or `select from mydataset.newtable$1`
give

```
Syntax error: Illegal input character "$" at [1:46]
```

Comment: Interesting, their documentation says this should work.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-integer-range-partitions?hl=en#table_decorators_on_integer_range_partitioned_tables . Might need to submit a bug report.

Comment: Looks like it's not supported by extract. I tried "bq head" with partition decorator and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The decorator $ is valid in LegacySQL, but you can opt by one of these options:

```
# LegacySQL, legacy sql is used by default in the following command. 
# From the UI you need to change it in More -> Query Settings
bq query 'SELECT * from mydataset.newtable$10'
```

or

```
# StandardSQL, the option use_legacy_sql=false force to use standard sql 
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * from mydataset.newtable WHERE customer_id BETWEEN 10 AND 20'
```

Regarding the bq extract command I could export after removing :

```
$ bq extract myproject:mydataset.newtable$1 gs://mybucket/newtable.csv
Waiting on bqjob_..._000001701cb5d260_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
$ gsutil cat gs://mybucket/newtable.csv
customer_id,date1
18,2020-10-01
1,2019-10-01
2,2019-10-02
$
```

**Edit:**

After checking your comment below, you are correct, the bq extract above returns all the data.

The doc [Exporting table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#exporting_table_data) suggests that 'mydataset.table$N'should work. But when the scape character (\) is used, this error is returned: Partition key is invalid: key: "N"

Since there are not documentation that indicates this is possible, I have already created a FR to add this funtionality. You can monitor this request in [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/149753341), it is important to note that there is not an ETA for its resolution.

Comment: Thanks. I think without the backslash your command just extracts the whole table. bash interprets $1 as an argument, which will be an empty string. E.g. `echo hello$1` gives `hello`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been [solved](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149154239) by Google, so the following command works as expected:

```
bq extract myproject:mydataset.newtable\$1 gs://mybucket/newtable.csv
```